# Qual a diferença desses parâmetros (array) nesses métodos?

Tags: php, array, parâmetros, referência

Vejo muito isso em métodos

```
class Exemplo
{
    public function exemplo1(array $parameters = array())
    {
    }

    public function exemplo2(array $parameters)
    {
    }

    public function exemplo3($parameters = array())
    {
    }
}
```

Isso significa que `$parameters` é um *array*, mas qual a diferença entre essas implementações?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dois conceitos importantes que você precisa entender são o de [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php) e [valor padrão do parâmetro](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

O *type hinting* **obriga** que argumento passado tenha um tipo específico (no caso um `array`).

A partir do PHP 7 podemos fazer *type hinting* dos [tipos primitivos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724677/php-type-hinting-to-primitive-values) (`int`, `string`, `float`).

Antes do PHP 7 o *type hinting* é limitado a Objetos, Interfaces, *arrays* e *closures*.

Agora o valor padrão do parâmetro, é o valor que o parâmetro irá assumir caso **não** seja passado nada para aquele parâmetro. Entenda como um parâmetro **opcional**.

Tomando seus exemplos, você então teria:

```
// Um método que obriga que o argumento seja um array 
// mas aceita uma chamada sem parâmetros:
public function exemplo1(array $parameters = array()){ }

$obj->exemplo1();

// Obriga que o argumento seja um array, e que o parâmetro seja passado: 
public function exemplo2(array $parameters){ }

$obj->exemplo2(array('id' => 1));

// Se nada for passado como argumento, assumirá o valor de um array vazio, 
// mas te permite passar outros tipos como argumento
public function exemplo3($parameters = array()){ }

$obj->exemplo3("Eu nao sou um array, mas tudo bem!");
```

Ao passar um valor padrão que não satisfaça o *type hinting*, será retornado um erro:

```
// Type hinting de array e valor padrão string
public function test(array $teste = "array")
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with array type hint can only be an array or NULL

Comment: Obrogado gmsantos, pela sua atenção! Entendi perfeitamente...

Answer (score 11):

Os dois primeiros estão indicando explicitamente que o parâmetro deve receber um *array*. O último não, um valor de qualquer tipo pode ser passado. Isto é chamado [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) no PHP.

O primeiro e o último inicializam o parâmetro com um *array* vazio **se** nenhum valor for passado para ele. A prioridade será do argumento passado se ele existir.

Comment: Obrigado bigown, pela sua atenção!

Answer (score 7):

Esse primeiro método define `$parameters` deve obrigatoriamente ser um array caso seja passado um valor diferente disso é gerado um erro, caso não seja passado nenhum argumento `parameters` será tratado como um array vazio.

```
public function exemplo1(array $parameters = array())
```

Exemplo:

```
$e = new Exemplo();
$e->exemplo1(1);
```

Erro gerado:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Exemplo::exemplo1() must
>   be of the type array, integer given, called

Obriga que `parameters` seja um array, caso contrario gera o mesmo erro citado a acima, e seu valor padrão é NULL e não um array vazio como `exemplo1()`.

```
public function exemplo2(array $parameters)
```

Define que se nenhum argumento for passado `$parameters` será um array vazio, esse método aceita outros valores como por exemplo uma string ou inteiro.

```
public function exemplo3($parameters = array())
```

O tipo definido ao lado esquerdo do paramêtro é chamado de [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), isso garante que o tipo definido deve ser respeitado caso venha algo diferente um erro é lançado. Mas é não possível tipar paramêtros com tipos primitivos(int, float, sting),  int or string. Resources e Traits. Normalmente é colocado o nome de uma classe ou interface.

Comment: Obrigado rray, pela sua atenção! Entendi perfeitamente!

Answer (score 7):

Esse e meu entendimento

```
 public function exemplo2(array $parameters)
```

> A função esta **obrigando** que o programador passe uma `array`.

```
public function exemplo3($parameters = array())
```

> A função esta colocando o valor **padrão** como `array`, mas o programador pode passar qualquer coisa.

```
 public function exemplo1(array $parameters = array())
```

> A função **só aceita** valores do tipo `array` e o preenchimento e **opcional**, caso o programador não passe irá usar o valor **padrão** `array()`

Comment: Obrigado Icaro Martins, pela sua atenção!

Answer (score 3):

Na função `exemplo1` o `array` serve pra indicar que o parâmetro `$parameters` *deve* ser um array. Se a função for chamada com um parâmetro de outro tipo o PHP vai gerar um aviso (Warning) informando que o tipo passado é incorreto.

A parte `= array()` serve para inicializar o valor do parâmetro, o que o torna opcional na hora de chamar a função.

Comment: Obrigado André Ribeiro, pela sua atenção!

Answer (score 3):

Apenas pra complementar, como já dito nas demais respostas:

```
//O primeiro parâmetro deve ser array ou vazio (caso vazio assume `array()`)
public function exemplo1(array $parameters = array())

//O primeiro parâmetro deve ser um array e não pode ser vazio
public function exemplo2(array $parameters)

//O primeiro parâmetro deve ser de qualquer tipo, se vazio assume `array()`
public function exemplo3($parameters = array())
```

Agora os adicionais, os parâmetros usando type hinting passam a ser suportados nesta ordem:

## PHP 5.0.0

- `Class/interface`: O parâmetro O parâmetro deve ser uma instância de um determinado nome de uma classe ou interface.
- `self`: O parâmetro deve ser uma instância da mesma classe que o método é definido na. Isso só pode ser utilizado em métodos de classe e instância.

## PHP 5.1.0

- `array` O parâmetro de ser um array

## PHP 5.4.0

- `callable` O parametro dever uma uma função ou método ou algo que equivale aos mesmo que possa ser chamado assim `$param();` e equivale ao `is_callabe();`

## PHP 7.0.0

O [PHP7 (lançado em 3/Dez/2015)](http://php.net/archive/2015.php#id2015-12-03-1) passou a suportar vários tipos e no PHP7 passou a se chamar [**Type declarations**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) e passou a gerar um [TypeError exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) quando declarado uma parâmetro de um tipo diferente.

> atualmente ele se encontra na versão [7.0.3 (lançado em 4/Fev/2016)](http://php.net/archive/2016.php#id2016-02-04-1), é altamente recomendável que não use o 7.0.0, 7.0.1 e 7.0.2.

- `bool` o parâmetro dever se do tipo booleano (true ou false).
- `float` o parâmetro deve ser um numero com ponto flutuante (1.1, 2.5, 3.8, etc)
- `int` o parâmetro deve ser do tipo inteiro `1`, `2`, `3` por exemplo.
- `string` o parâmetro deve ser do tipo string.

### Tipos estrito (strict)

O PHP7 também passou a suportar o "strict mode" para declaração de tipos como por exemplo:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function sum(int $a, int $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

var_dump(sum(1, 2));
var_dump(sum(1.5, 2.5));
```

O resultado será este erro:

```
int(3)

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to sum() must be of the type integer, float given, called in - on line 9 and defined in -:4
Stack trace:
#0 -(9): sum(1.5, 2.5)
#1 {main}
  thrown in - on line 4
```

### Retorno de tipo

Também passou a ser suportado no PHP7 o retorno de tipo, por exemplo:

```
<?php
function sum($a, $b): float {
    return $a + $b;
}

var_dump(sum(1, 2));
```

Este também suporta o `strict`

Answer (score 0):

#### Sobre cada método

Basicamente o que muda é apenas a assinatura do método, eles poderiam estar fazendo a mesma coisa.

**Método `exemplo1`:** é esperado um valor do tipo array, além disso, este método está recebendo um valor padrão que é um array vazio, o que faz o parâmetro ser opcional.

**Método `exemplo2`:** neste método é esperado um valor do tipo array. O  parâmetro não é opcional nesse caso.

**Método `exemplo3`:** o método aceita qualquer tipo de valor, pois nenhum type hinting foi definido. Além disso, o parâmetro em questão é opcional e está recebendo um array como valor padrão, entretanto ele não está restrito a receber somente arrays.