# O que a aplicação ganha utilizando Type Hint?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

No PHP 5 sabemos que foi adicionado o [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) e agora podemos declarar e forçar o tipo do parâmetro que uma função receberá. Acredito que ajudará no tratamento dos dados de forma mais precisa, porém qual o ganho de utilizá-lo, visto que ele não funciona também com tipos primitivos?

De imediato só penso na legibilidade de código, mas daí temos as *tags* de documentação que podemos informar o tipo do parâmetro e o retorno daquela função.

Algumas discussões sobre *type hinting*:

[SoPT 53476#53476](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53475/atribuir-tipo-para-par%C3%A2metros/53476#53476)

[SoPT 48825#48825](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48813/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-desses-parametros-array-nesses-m%C3%A9todos/48825#48825)

[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724696/1432957)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pelas informações que a pergunta mostra já ter a resposta não pode fugir da obviedade.

Além da melhor documentação como já mencionada, e isto não pode ser minimizado, se ganha segurança de tipos. Desta forma o código obriga que o argumento na chamada seja do tipo especificado. Isto já está explicado nas perguntas *linkadas*.

O fato de não permitir outros tipos prejudica que toda a aplicação tenha esta segurança, mas alguma segurança é melhor que nenhuma. E como provavelmente no futuro existirá para todos os tipos (já existe agora), já está com meio caminho andado na aplicação atual.

Em sistemas maiores fica muito mais robusto fazer isto. É uma pena que por enquanto não dê para obrigar usar isto em todos os lugares ou dizer que quer que o tipo seja dinâmico mesmo. Em sistemas pequenos, ou seja, *scripts*, não é importante, mas em grandes é difícil manter tudo funcionando corretamente sem oferecer garantias. Este meio é mais fácil e mais eficaz que fazer o tratamento no corpo da função ou escrever testes para verificar se os tipos foram usados corretamente. Se ganha produtividade e robustez, ainda que limitada até poder usar todos os tipos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Convém citar o `declare(strict_types=1)` que evita o *cast mágico* para o tipo esperado?

Comment: Isso é novo, né? Está citado :D

Answer (score 5):

Um adendo a resposta existente, no PHP7 deixa de se chamar *type hinting* e passa a se chamar [*type declaration*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) pois este agora suporta os tipos `int`, `bool`, `float` e `string`, além dos já existentes no php5, como classes, interfaces, funções e arrays, eu coloquei uma explicação mais detalhada em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115671/3635

Na pratica o *type hinting* (php5) ou *type declaration* php7 são opcionais e tecnicamente você pode fazer a verificação das variáveis sem usar eles, assim por exemplo:

### PHP5

Com indução de tipos:

```
<?php
function filterLetters($a) {
    if (is_array($a)) {
        return array_filter($a, 'ctype_alpha');
    }

    return false;
}

//Causa erro
var_dump(filterLetters(array('a', 'b', 'cdef', 0, 1, 3, 'a1')));

//Causa erro
var_dump(filterLetters('abc'));
```

Com indução de tipos:

```
<?php
function filterLetters(array $a) {
    return array_filter($a, 'ctype_alpha');
}

//retorna array(a, b, cdef)
var_dump(filterLetters(array('a', 'b', 'cdef', 0, 1, 3, 'a1')));

//causa erro
var_dump(filterLetters('abc'));
```

### PHP7

Sem declaração de tipos:

```
function unixtimeToTimestamp($a) {
    if (is_int($a)) {
        return gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a);
    }

    return false;
}

//Retorna algo como 2001-09-11 10:10:30
var_dump(unixtimeToTimestamp(1000203030));

//Retorna false
var_dump(unixtimeToTimestamp(1123123123.5));
```

No entanto veja que foi necessário criar uma `if` e usar `is_int`, agora no PHP7 você poderá fazer algo como:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function unixtimeToTimestamp(int $a) {
    return gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a);
}

var_dump(unixtimeToTimestamp(1000203030));

//Causa erro
var_dump(unixtimeToTimestamp(1123123123.5));
```

claro que neste caso usamos `declare(strict_types=1);` para evitar alguns que seriam considerados implícitos" para um "cast", como `float` para `int`

### Conclusão

Notou como ficou mais fácil com o *type hinting* ou com o *type declaration*? Esse é o intuito básico dele(s).