# O que é a sintaxe que vem antes do nome da variável em parâmetros de funções?

Tags: php, tipagem, sintaxe, parâmetros

Lendo a documentação do PHP me deparei com o seguinte exemplo:

```
function bar(A $a = null, $b) {} // Ainda permitido
function bar(?A $a, $b) {}       // Recomendado
```

Dei uma pesquisada e descobri a função do `?`, porém o que significa o `A` sendo passado antes da variável `$a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nos dois casos é o tipo da variáveis sendo declarada ali, no caso específico do exemplo a variável é um parâmetro, então a variável será tipada, só deve ser usada com valores desse tipo. Não tem nada sendo passado aí.

Então `$a` deve conter um valor do tipo `A`, ou então do tipo `?A` que o tipo será certamente `A`, mas pode ter um valor nulo.

Obviamente `A` é um péssimo nome de tipo ou qualquer outra coisa, já que não diz o que é aquilo, e justamente por isso a documentação não é boa nisso.

Até entendo que o objetivo da documentação é só mostrar um aspecto daquilo, mas é estranho falar em "recomendado" sendo que em uma variável se usa do jeito recomendado, mas outra usa do jeito que não é mais recomendado, ou seja, é declarada sem o [*type hint*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82465/101).

PHP decidiu que não quer mais ser uma linguagem de *script* e quer agora concorrer com Java, C#, Swift, Kotlin, C++, etc. Claro que isso não é possível sem quebrar compatibilidade com tudo o que já foi feito do jeito *script*, não permitindo que seja uma boa transição e obrigando aceitar o que agora é considerado o jeito errado de fazer, portanto depende da disciplina do programador fazer da forma mais adequada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito estranho mesmo. Quando pesquisei sobre o `?`, vi que ele vinha antes de variáveis e não do tipo, então imaginei que estava deixando passar algo. Muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: Ressaltando @FURIUS a documentação diz que esse "método" de declaração significa que o valor pode ser do "tipo" especificado ou nulo, ou seja, 2:```bar(null, "aaaaa")``` como o @Maniero mencionou esse é um péssimo nome de tipo (te obriga a entender uma sigla que não tem nada haver..)