# Novos tipos do PHP: qual a vantagem de usar o tipo de retorno void e qual a diferença com o tipo never introduzido recentemente?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, tipagem, return, void

O ganho no uso de `void` como tipo de retorno de métodos/funções é apenas de legibilidade?

E o tipo `never` introduzido nas últimas versões (mais especificamente na versão 8.1) do PHP é semelhante ao `void`? Quais os contextos de seu uso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Já respondi sobre a vantagem de usar a tipagem declarada de tipos em funções [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82465/101) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93707/101). O ganho é principalmente em robustez. Quem sabe um dia o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) possa dar algum ganho de performance em algumas situações quando há o tipo explícito.

Ter o tipo declarado e documentado pode melhorar a facilidade de entender o que a função exerce e o que se espera fazer com ela, então pode facilitar um pouco o uso do recurso. O código em si não chega ficar mais legível por causa disso, mas a documentação fica, se é que podemos usar esse termo.

## `void`

`void` é um tipo, pelo menos na maioria das linguagens, que indica que não deve ter nada ali, nem mesmo um valor nulo para indicar invalidade. Ele é muito usado em tipos de retorno de funções.

Em geral, em muitas linguagens, ele impede de usar o resultado da função em uma expressão, você não poderia nem chamar em um `echo` por exemplo, mas não em PHP que é aceito e funciona normalmente, não podendo valer alguma coisa dependendo do contexto, até pode ser usado como se fosse um 0.

Então a vantagem dele, além da geral já citada acima, é que no `return` ele dará errado se tentar colocar alguma coisa. Não é uma ótima vantagem, mas ajuda.

```
function funcao(): void {
    return 1; // dá erro
}
```

## `never`

Já o `never` só deve ser usado em uma função que nunca retorna, ou seja, ela nunca terminará de executar, é uma função de fim de execução do *script*. Raramente ele é útil, mas é interessante informar quando a função tem essa característica de matar a execução em algum momento dela e que nada depois dali será executado. Funções assim só devem ser chamadas no fim do *script* ou condicionalmente, se fizer sentido. Se a função tiver esse tipo de retorno declarado não pode ter um `return` dentro da função, nem mesmo implicitamente poderá ter um.

```
function funcao(): never {
    exit();
    return 'fim'; // dá erro
}
```

Mas também dá erro porque há um `return` implícito no fim da função:

```
function funcao(): never {
    if (false) exit();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/VoidNever.php).

Uma exceção também pode ser usada para encerrar a função sem um `return`.

Então com eles o código fica mais robusto e documenta melhor a intenção.