# Variável não é atualizada no construtor

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, php-7, construtor

Estou aprendendo OO e me aventurando no PHP, só que acabei me deparando com algo que eu creio que na teoria deveria funcionar, mas na prática não funciona.

```
<?php 

class Users{

  public $name; 
  public $idade;
  public $email;
  private $senha;

  function __construct($name, $idade, $email, $senha){
    $this->name = (string) $name;
    $this->idade = (int) $idade;
    $this->email = (string) $email;
    $this->senha = $this->setPassword($senha);
    echo "O objeto foi contruido!";

  }

  function setPassword($senha){
    if (strlen($senha) > 8 and strlen($senha) < 13):
        $this->senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    else:
        die ('Sua senha deve conter entre 8 e 13 caracters');
    endif;
  }
}
```

Ai quando eu uso :

```
$pessoa = new Users("Flavio", 19, "flvdeveloper@gmail.com", "testando123");
var_dump($pessoa);
```

Ele printa :

```
O objeto foi contruido!
C:\wamp\www\ws_php\n.php:6:
object(Users)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'Flavio' (length=6)
  public 'idade' => int 19
  public 'email' => string 'flvdeveloper@gmail.com' (length=22)
  private 'senha' => null
```

a senha fica null.

mas quando eu tento :

```
$pessoa->setPassword("testando123");
```

ele funciona normalmente.

Onde estou errando?

Mais uma dúvida que tenho é sobre algo que vi que é chamado de *type hinting* algo assim eu creio.

Eu estou dizendo aqui que quero `$nome` só aceite o tipo *string*:

```
$this->name = (string) $name; // AQUI
$this->idade = (int) $idade;
$this->email = (string) $email;
$this->senha = $this->setPassword($senha);
```

mas eu vi que no PHP 7 é possível passar nos parâmetros da função.

```
function __construct(string $name, int $idade, string $email, $senha)
```

Mas quando faço isso não funciona e me é retornando um erro no console, estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Questão de codestyle: é mais comum usar `{}` ao invés de `:` em ifs e afins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É um erro bem simples, mas ao mesmo tempo, chatinho de se perceber, e está aqui

```
$this->senha = $this->setPassword($senha);
```

Você está chamando o método

```
$this->senha = $this->setPassword($senha);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

E esse método não retorna nada (nulo).

Só que você pega esse nulo e guarda ele em `$this->senha` logo em seguida:

```
$this->senha =  $this->setPassword($senha);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Ou seja, você acabou de sobreescrever o que o `setPassword` criou.

O correto seria tirar a atribuição, e deixar o método trabalhar sozinho:

```
function __construct($name, $idade, $email, $senha){
    $this->name = (string) $name;
    $this->idade = (int) $idade;
    $this->email = (string) $email;
    $this->setPassword($senha);
    echo "O objeto foi contruido!";
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/u5Owsd)**.

Sobre o *Type Hinting*, como você usou a tag [php7](/questions/tagged/php7), vale dizer que agora são *Type Declarations*, mas infelizmente não são tão adequadas para ajudar no seu caso, pois elas funcionam de maneira um pouco específica.

Quando você declara na função, por exemplo um *bool*, a função vai esperar uma "instancia de bool", e não o tipo primitivo.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Outra coisa: `$a = ( tipo ) $b;` são *casts*, não tem relação com *Type Declaration* nem *Hinting*. No seu caso, não vão evitar que a pessoa use valores errados.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.type-juggling.php

Finalmente, em vez do `die();` sugeriria você criar uma flag no seu código para dizer se o objeto é válido ou não.

Algo assim:

```
class Users{
  public $name; 
  public $idade;
  public $email;
  public $isValid;
  private $senha;

  function __construct($name, $idade, $email, $senha){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->idade = $idade;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->isValid = $this->setPassword($senha);
  }

  function setPassword($senha){
    if (strlen($senha) > 8 and strlen($senha) < 13) {
      $this->senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
      return true;
  } else {
      $this->senha = '';
      return false;
  }

  function isValid(){
    return $this->isValid;
  }
```

Modo de usar:

```
$pessoa = new Users( 'Flavio', 19, 'flvdeveloper@gmail.com', 'testando123' );
if( $pessoa->isValid() ) {
    // faz o que tem que fazer
else {
    // avisa que deu problema
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Fiz algumas pequenas alterações. O erro é porque está chamando o método de forma errada, ele não retorna nada, portanto não pode atribuir para uma variável. Se quer que ele execute, basta chamá-lo.

```
class Users {
    public $name; 
    public $idade;
    public $email;
    private $senha;
    function __construct($name, $idade, $email, $senha){ 
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->setPassword($senha);
        echo "O objeto foi contruido!";
    }
    function setPassword($senha) {
        if (strlen($senha) > 8 and strlen($senha) < 13) {
            $this->senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        } else {
            die ('Sua senha deve conter entre 8 e 13 caracters');
        }
    }
}
$pessoa = new Users("Flavio", 19, "flvdeveloper@gmail.com", "testando123");
var_dump($pessoa);
$pessoa->setPassword("testando123");
var_dump($pessoa);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EBrby6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/idukhwsu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Constructor2.php).

Tirei os *casts*. Eles só vão trazer problemas, ele não faz o que imagina. *Cast* é para converter um dado para outro. Se der certo ótimo, se falhar não terá uma informação válida.

Se deseja garantir que os tipos dos parâmetros sejam do jeito que deseja terá que usar `if` mesmo. Ou no PHP 7 usar o *type hinting*, conforme tentou (mas nem todos tipos podem ser usados ainda, por isso o erro). Veja:

- [Atribuir tipo para parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53475/101)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116787/101
- [PHP 7 tem tipagem de argumentos e de retorno, mas é opcional. Isso é bom ou ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107705/101)
- [Qual a diferença desses parâmetros (array) nesses métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48813/101)

Answer (score 3):

O problema inicial é que você definiu duas vezes a propriedade `password` como já dito em [outras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150070/4751) [respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150074/4751).

Como você está começando, gostaria de complementar com alguns pontos legais de boas práticas.

O primeiro é o uso do `:` no `if` e em outras estruturas. Apesar de funcionar, o foco do `:` é para utilizar em templates:

```
<?php if ($var instanceof Legume): ?>
    Pode ser uma batata!
<?php else: ?>
    Não é uma batata
<?php endif; ?>
```

Num arquivo onde só existe código, prefira usar as `{}`

```
if ($var instanceof Legume) {
    Pode ser uma batata!
} else {
    Não é uma batata
}
```

Outro ponto é a visibilidade dos métodos. O PHP usa `function` para definir os métodos e não é obrigatório definir a visibilidade. Caso nada seja definido o método é tratado como `public`. Esse comportamento vem do PHP 4, e hoje em dia, é melhor deixar explícito que algo é `public`.

Para ter uma ideia melhor de como escrever o código, você pode se basear no code style do [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#11-example). Esse é o padrão adotado por vários projetos em PHP e isso garante que o código escrito é parecido visualmente, independente de quem escreveu o código.

Por fim, prefira disparar uma `Exception` ao invés de fazer um `die` e encerrar seu script todo.

Veja algumas referencias sobre *Exceptions*:

- [Quando usar Exceptions no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112554/quando-usar-exceptions-no-php)
- [Quais são as Exceptions nativas do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58344/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-exceptions-nativas-do-php)

Por fim, se código pode chegar a ficar dessa forma:

```
// Arquivo Users.php
class Users 
{
    public $name; 
    public $idade;
    public $email;
    private $senha;

    public function __construct($name, $idade, $email, $senha){ 
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->setPassword($senha);
        echo "O objeto foi contruido!";
    }

    public function setPassword($senha) {
        if (strlen($senha) > 8 and strlen($senha) < 13) {
            $this->senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'Sua senha deve conter entre 8 e 13 caracteres'
            );
        }
    }
}

// Arquivo index.php
try {
    $pessoa = new Users("Flavio", 19, "flvdeveloper@gmail.com", "testando123");
    var_dump($pessoa);

    // Aqui vai dar erro
    $pessoa->setPassword("ba");
    var_dump($pessoa);

catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Faz alguma magia negra.

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!